# Where can npm packages be used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Where can npm packages be used? I used some in Angular and some in Node, but can all npm packages be used in every Javascript runtime environment?

edit: for all those who downvoted this question, if i can't get help here as a newbie, where can I get?

Answer (score 2):

npm can used for any environment. it based on what you need. specially for javascript, it has million packages that can be used to.

Answer (score 1):

No, not all npm packages can be used in any environment.

Answer (score 0):

Npm is just a package management system. Theoretically yes you can run packages in browser or node environment. But that is not commonly the case.

Npm packages are mostly used in node environment (not the browser). You can write servers with packages such as express, or run tasks such as gulp with nodejs..

If you want to do front end development, bower is a popular choice.

The difference is how dependencies gets managed.

Comment: Bower's own website suggests not using it anymore in favor of Yarn.  Myself, I have found that using npm for both back-end and front-end development makes things simpler; you just npm init your `public` or `client` folder and install clientside packages there.

Comment: Npm is used all over for browser package management, e.g., React apps commonly use npm and webpack.

Answer (score 0):

npm itself can be used to pull and manage any packages that are in a compatible repository (or on the local file system, or in git, etc).

Whether you can use a given package in a given environment, however, is entirely up to the maintainer of that particular package.  npm itself puts no restrictions on that and doesn't even (unfortunately) have an easy system for indicating the environments in which a package is applicable.

By environment, it's more complicated than just web and browser.  It's also OS in some cases (not all Node packages are OS independent).  But even for just the web and browser, realize that some things just don't make sense in some environments.  Your clientside browser application can't touch the client's file system, so file handling modules are going to have a hard time working there.

Finally, as I said in a comment, I would say that while there are a lot of options for package managing of JS apps out there, I find npm is a pretty solid one to use in all environments.  It creates a standard you can stick to.  That said, it does mean that you have to do your due diligence on package selection to make sure that the thing you're pulling in makes sense for where you're using it.